# resize array and add element c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dynamic-arrays

Hey i know this is simple but for some reason i'm having a tougher time than i thought. All im trying to is if the size of my dynamic array is equal to the actual amount of elements that are in it (meaning it is full) then i want to double the size of the array and add the element

```
    int add_element(int *array, int size , int &count)
{
    int temp;
    cout << "What number do you want to add ? " << endl;
    cin >> temp;
    if(count = size)
    {
        copy(array, size);
        count++;
        array[count] = temp;
    }
    return count;
}

void copy(int *oldArr  , int size)
{
    int temp = size * 2;
    int *newArr = new int[temp];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        newArr[i] = oldArr[i];

    }
    //delete[] oldArr;
    oldArr = NULL;
    oldArr = newArr;
    delete[] oldArr;
```

the issue im having is that is not actually doubling the size of the array because when i try to look for the element it just returns the address space.
Any help would be a appreciated

***********EDIT*********
i went ahead an made these changes but my array still doesnt seem to be changing size

```
void add_element(int* &array, int size , int &count)
{
    int temp;
    cout << "What number do you want to add ? " << endl;
    cin >> temp;
    if(count ==  size)
    {
        copy(array, size);
        count++;
        array[count] = temp;
    }

}

void copy(int* &oldArr  , int size)
{
    int temp = size * 2;
    int *newArr = new int[temp];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        newArr[i] = oldArr[i];

    }

    delete[] oldArr;
    oldArr = newArr;
```

Comment: `count = size` should be `==` instead.

Comment: @buc good catch but its still not increasing the size of the array

Comment: I just noticed, found 3 more mistakes, see my answer.

Comment: Did you declare `copy` before your `add_element`? If not, and you also declared `using namespace std` earlier (based on cout and cin, it looks like you did), you might be actually using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy in `add_element`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your code.

First, in `add_element` you wanted to test if the item count equals to the array size, but instead you accidentally overwrite the `count` variable:

```
if(count = size)   // this assigns count
```

should be replaced with

```
if(count == size)
```

Second, you delete the newly allocated array instead of the old one:

```
oldArr = newArr;
delete[] oldArr;    // this will effectively deallocate newArr
```

You should change the order these lines:

```
delete[] oldArr;    // it deletes oldArr
oldArr = newArr;    // and then points it to newArr
```

Third, you pass the pointer to your array by value. This way, when a new array is allocated, you won't be able to return the address of the new array to the caller of your functions. You should pass the array pointer by reference, similarly to `count`:

```
int add_element(int* &array, int size, int &count)
```

and

```
void copy(int* &oldArr, int size)
```

Fourth, you return the `count` twice from the function `add_element`: both as a return value, and as an in-out argument. Although, this is technically not a problem, but definitely unnecessary. I suggest changing `add_element` to return `void`.

**Update**:

And at last, but not at least, there is a fifth issue that I overlooked. Similarly to how the new array pointer needs to be returned from the functions, the same has to be done with the array size as well. So `size` should be passed by reference and it should be properly updated:

```
int add_element(int* &array, int &size, int &count)
```

and

```
void copy(int* &oldArr, int &size) {   // pass size by reference
    int temp = size * 2;

    // ...

    oldArr = newArr;
    size = temp;   // update size
}
```

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply ... i went ahead an made those changes but it still doesnt seem to be updating the size of my array and i'm really not sure why ..... i went ahead an made the edits to my original post

Comment: I updated my answer, but at this point you should have figured it out by yourself: if you want to change a value within a function you either have to return it or pass it by pointer or reference.